# exploding a search string

Tags: php, regex, search

I'm trying to make a search string, which can accept a query like this:

```
$string = 'title -launch category:technology -tag:news -tag:"outer space"$';
```

Here's a quick explanation of what I want to do:

```
$ = suffix indicating that the match should be exact
" = double quotes indicate that the multi-word is taken as a single keyword
- = a prefix indicating that the keyword is excluded
```

Here's my current parser:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\w+)\:"(\w+)/', '"${1}:${2}', $string);
$array = str_getcsv($string, ' ');
```

I was using this above code before, but it doesn't work as intended with the keywords starting on searches like **-tag:"outer space"**. The code above doesn't recognize strings starting with - character and breaks the keyword at the whitespace between the **outer** and **space**, despite being enclosed with double quotes.

EDIT: What I'm trying to do with that code is to preg_replace -tag:"outer space" into "-tag:outer space" so that they won't be broken when I pass the string to str_getcsv().

Comment: Try `(\w+):"([^"]+)"` or `(\w+):(?|"([^"]+)"|(\S+))`

Comment: I tried putting both on the first parameter of preg_replace() but they both still do the same, breaking the -tag:"outer space" into -tag:outer and space.

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm new to this, but I think the problem starts on str_getcsv() since it's still trying to break the keyword into two on the whitespace despite being quoted. I need it to work by including the - character. That means that the regex isn't properly enclosing the terms in quotes for the str_getcsv().

Comment: Why use `str_getcsv` at all? Use `preg_match_all`

Comment: IDK about it yet, but I'd sure love to learn how to do this in preg_match_all().

Comment: I don't think that's what I wanted. I need the parsing to include keywords without a colon, and I need the keywords to include the - in their beginning whenever they are present.

Comment: I see, sorry, I misunderstood the question. Try https://regex101.com/r/iuHyFq/3, see the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/5cmv4a)

Comment: Wow, that works. I already figured it out using a different conditon, but I'll post both for reference.

Comment: Why post then? It is my answer, I will post and explain.

Comment: I'll wait and check your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `preg_replace` like this:

```
 preg_replace('/(-?\w+:)"([^"]+)"/', '"$1$2"', $str);
```

See the [PHP demo online](https://ideone.com/5cmv4a).

The regex matches:

- `(-?\w+:)` - Capturing group 1: an optional `-` (`?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences), then 1+ letters/digits/underscores and a `:`
- `"` - a double quote (it will be removed)
- `([^"]+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more chars other than a double quote
- `"` - a double quote

The replacement pattern is `"$1$2"`: `"`, capturing group 1 value,
capturing group 2 value, and a `"`.

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iuHyFq/3).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and patience. I'm glad that I asked. I learned a new thing today.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\-?)(\w+?\:?)"(\w+)/', '"$1$2$3', $string);
$array = str_getcsv($string, ' ');
```

I considered formats like -"top ten" for quoted multi-word keywords that doesn't have a category/tag + colon prefix.

I'm sorry for being slow, I'm new on regex, php and programming in general and this is also my first post in stackoverflow. I'm trying to learn it as a personal hobby. I'm glad that I learned something new today. I'll be reading more about regex since it looks like it can do a lot of stuff.